# Auto-wiring on MentaContainer not working?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autowired

I am trying to figure out why auto-wiring is not working for my situation below. Would anyone be able to help me out here?

```
public interface UserDAO {
    // ..
}

public class DBUserDAO implements UserDAO {
    private Connection conn;

    public void setConn(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public Connection getConn() {
        return conn;
    }

    // ..
}

Container container = new MentaContainer();

c.ioc(Connection.class, connFactory);
c.ioc(UserDAO.class, DBUserDAO.class);
c.autowire(Connection.class);

Connection conn = c.get(Connection.class); // not NULL !!! good!
UserDAO userDAO = c.get(UserDAO.class);

System.out.println("CONN: " + ((DBUserDAO) userDAO).getConn()); // prints "CONN: null"
```

I don't know why the connection is always null inside the DBUserDAO! :(

EDIT: I am using [MentaContainer](http://mentacontainer.soliveirajr.com)

Comment: @JohnPristine Sorry! I added it to the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened here is that the container has no way to know that your bean property is "conn". Because you did not define anything it has to assume that it is "connection". A simple change from `c.autowire(Connection.class)` to `c.autowire(Connection.class, "conn")` will fix the problem. Or you can change your property to "connection" as @Sérgio Michels said which not just works but it is also a better naming convention in my opinion.

Actually my favorite fix for that is to use constructor injection instead of setter injection. Then you don't have to mess with property names:

```
public interface UserDAO {
    // ..
}

public class DBUserDAO implements UserDAO {

    private final Connection conn;

    public DBUserDAO(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    // ..
}

Container container = new MentaContainer();

c.ioc(Connection.class, connFactory);
c.ioc(UserDAO.class, DBUserDAO.class);
c.autowire(Connection.class);
```

Because constructor (*or any methods*) parameters in Java have no names, the container will only try to match the types and it will succeed matching the autowired `Connection.class` to the constructor arguments. And it is impossible for you to have a DBUserDAO without a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Never use it, but looking at the docs, your autowire will not work because you already put the UserDAO in the context. So I think the correct is:

```
c.ioc(Connection.class, connFactory);
c.autowire(Connection.class); //from now, every object that have connection will be autowired.
c.ioc(UserDAO.class, DBUserDAO.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but switching those lines did not change anything. It is still null. :(

Comment: What happens if you change the name of property and methods to `connection` instead of `conn`?